# CliwPw - Yet Another Python3 Password Manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, hashcode, aes

I wrote a (very) simply Python3 password manager to familiarize myself with Sqlite3, and for fun. I am aware that there are already a variety of password managers out there, but I wanted something simple and *secure(?)* to replace the very insecure bashrc function that I use to generate random passwords and store them with a quick description on the fly. I tried writing a password manager in bash that used hashing and GPG, but decided it was easier to do in Python.

I am looking for advice on how to improve the security of my program. I have implemented features such as:

- Timeout if idle
- Remove key from memory before exit
- Master key is hashed with sha256 and salted

The entire program is available [here](https://github.com/darkerego/clipw) on github, but the functionality I am looking for advise on is the hashing and crypto functions:

Hash Lib:

```
import hmac
import random
import string
from _hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac
from getpass import getpass
from os import urandom, mkdir
from typing import Tuple
from lib.clipw_conf import debug, config_dir, config_file


class HashPass(object):
    """
    Wrapper Class for password hashing functions
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Empty __init__ function
        """
        pass

    def hash_new_password(self, password: str) -> Tuple[bytes, bytes]:
        """
        Hash the provided password with a randomly-generated salt and return the
        salt and hash to store in the database.
        :return salt, password hash
        """

        salt = urandom(16)
        pw_hash = pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode(), salt, 100000)
        return salt, pw_hash

    def check_pw_padding(self, pw):
        """
        Check that password length is AES compliant, add padding if not
        :param pw: password
        :return: password with buffering
        """

        pw_len = len(pw)
        if pw_len <= 8:
            while pw_len % 8 != 0:
                pw += '0'
                pw_len = (len(pw))
        if pw_len <= 16:
            while pw_len % 16 != 0:
                pw += '0'
                pw_len = (len(pw))
        if pw_len <= 32:
            while pw_len % 32 != 0:
                pw += '0'
                pw_len = (len(pw))

        return pw

    def is_correct_password(self, salt: bytes, pw_hash: bytes, password: str) -> bool:
        """
        Given a previously-stored salt and hash, and a password provided by a user
        trying to log in, check whether the password is correct.
        """

        return hmac.compare_digest(
            pw_hash,
            pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password.encode(), salt, 100000)
        )

    def generate_hash(self, pw):
        """
        Generate a Hash and Salt from a password
        :param self: password to hash
        :return: salt and hash
        """

        salt, pw_hash = self.hash_new_password(pw)
        salt = salt.hex()
        pw_hash = pw_hash.hex()
        if self.is_correct_password(bytes.fromhex(salt), bytes.fromhex(pw_hash), pw):
            if debug:
                print('Test Succeeded!')
                print("Salt: %s" % salt)
                print("Hash: %s" % pw_hash)
            return salt, pw_hash
        else:
            return False

    def store_master_password(self):
        """
        Upon init, store users master key to disc
        :return: True on success
        """

        try:
            mkdir(config_dir)
        except FileExistsError as err:
            pass
        else:
            print('Created config directory %s' % config_dir)
        # hash a password
        while True:
            pw = getpass('Password: ')
            pw2 = getpass('Confirm: ')
            try:
                assert pw == pw2
            except AssertionError:
                print('Passwords do not match. Try again')
            else:
                pw_len = len(pw)
                if pw_len > 32 or pw_len < 8:
                    print('Password must be at least 8 and no more than 32 characters.')
                else:
                    s, p = self.generate_hash(pw)
                    hash_str = str(s + ":" + p)
                    with open(config_file, 'w+') as f:
                        f.write(hash_str)
                    return True

    def get_master_password(self):
        """
        Function to create an AES friendly Master Password
        to encrypt all the passwords in the database...
        Because they key needs to be either 8 or 16 characters,
        we will add padding until it if an appropriate length.
        :return: byte encoded password string
        """
        with open(config_file, 'r') as ff:
            master_hash = ff.read()
            _salt = master_hash.split(':')[0]
            _hash = master_hash.split(':')[1]
            master_pw = getpass("Master Password: ")
            if self.is_correct_password(bytes.fromhex(_salt), bytes.fromhex(_hash), master_pw):
                print('Success!')
                master_pw = self.check_pw_padding(master_pw)
                return master_pw.encode()
            else:
                print('Incorrect Password')
                exit(1)

    def store_password(self):
        """
        Function to get a password and confirm user enters it twice correctly.
        :return: password
        """
        while True:
            pw = getpass('Password: ')
            pw2 = getpass('Confirm: ')
            try:
                assert pw == pw2
            except AssertionError:
                print('Passwords do not match.')
            else:
                return pw

    def random_password(self, n: int = 12) -> object:
        """
        Generate a random password of length n
        :param n: length of password to generate
        :return: password string
        """
        random_source = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        password = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
        password += random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
        password += random.choice(string.digits)
        password += random.choice(string.punctuation)

        for i in range(n):
            password += random.choice(random_source)

        password_list = list(password)
        random.SystemRandom().shuffle(password_list)
        password = ''.join(password_list)[:n]
        return password
```

> I am curious about the function `check_pw_padding`, which adds padding to the key that it is of a compliant length  for the AES
>   functions. I want the user to be able to enter a key of arbitraty length, however I need that key to work with AES-CTR mode, which means it must be either 8, 16, or 32 bytes characters long. I believe I am following standard practice here, but I wanted to ask the community for advice on whether or not my implimentation follows best practice.

AES Library:

```
import pyaes
import base64
from .clipw_conf import *


class HandleAes(object):
    """
    AES Encrypt/Decrypt Function
    """
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def remove_from_mem(self):
        self.key = None

    def encrypt_data(self, data):
        """
        ENCRYPTION
        AES CRT mode - 256 bit (8, 16, or 32 byte) key
        :param data: data to encrypt
        :return: base64 wrapper AES encrypted data
        """
        aes = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCTR(self.key)
        ciphertext = aes.encrypt(data)
        encoded = base64.b64encode(ciphertext).decode('utf-8')
        if debug:
            print('Encrypted data:', encoded)
        # show the encrypted data
        return encoded

    def decrypt_data(self, data):
        """
        DECRYPTION
        AES CRT mode decryption requires a new instance be created
        :param data: base64 encoded ciphertext
        :return: plaintext
        """
        aes = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCTR(self.key)
        # decrypted data is always binary, need to decode to plaintext
        decoded = base64.b64decode(data)
        decrypted = aes.decrypt(decoded).decode('utf-8')
        if debug:
            print('Decrypted data:', decrypted)
        return decrypted
```

> Is AES-CTR sufficient for this use case? I want to use a stream cipher because the data I am storing is going to be of arbitrary length. Of course, I could always add padding to the data that it stores, but if I don't need to do that, and if this library is secure and I can reuse it, that would be great. [This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/27776/block-chaining-modes-to-avoid/27780#27780) says that CTR is safe. Does my implementation follow best practice? Specifically, is it *sufficient*, or even *necessary* to ensure the key is cleared from memory by assisinging the variable None (in function `remove_from_mem`)

SQL Lib:

```
import sqlite3
from .clipw_conf import *


class Sql:
    """
    Wrapper object to handle sqlite functions
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.database_file = database_file

    def open(self):
        """
            Connect to SQL database
        """
        try:
            self.sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect(self.database_file)
        except Exception as err:
            print('Error connecting to database:', err)
        else:
            return self.sqlite_connection

    def close(self):
        """
        Close connection to SQL database
        :return:
        """
        try:
            self.sqlite_connection.close()
        except Exception as err:
            print('Error closing database:', err)
            return False

    def init_database(self):
        """
        Function to init database on first run.
        :return:
        """
        sqlite_connection = self.open()
        try:

            sqlite_create_table_query = '''CREATE TABLE Password_Store (
                                        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                        desc text NOT NULL,
                                        pass_hash text NOT NULL);'''

            cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
            print("Successfully Connected to SQLite")
            cursor.execute(sqlite_create_table_query)
            sqlite_connection.commit()
            print("SQLite table created")
            return True

        except sqlite3.Error as error:
            print("Error while creating a sqlite table:", error)
            return False
        finally:
            self.close()

    def edit_database(self, id, data, field):
        """
        Broken function to update a field of a row in the table
        :param id: primary key id for WHERE clause
        :param data: edited field data to replace in current db entry
        :param field: either desc (description) or pass_hash (password hash of entry)
        :return: True om success, false om fail
        """
        #  sqlite_connection = self.sqlite_connection
        sqlite_connection = self.open()
        try:
            cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()  # define our sqlite connection
            print("Connected to SQLite")
            if field == 'pass_hash':  # updating password field
                cursor.execute('''Update Password_Store SET pass_hash = ? WHERE id = ?''',
                               (data, id))  # 2md failed method
            else:
                cursor.execute('''UPDATE Password_Store SET desc = ? WHERE id = ?''', (data, id))
            sqlite_connection.commit()
            print("Record Updated successfully ")
            return True

        except sqlite3.Error as error:
            print("Failed to update sqlite table", error)
            return False
        finally:
            self.close()

    def append_database(self, new_passwd, pw_description):
        """
        :param new_passwd: entry's password to append
        :param pw_description: entry's password description to append
        :return:
        """
        #  sqlite_connection = self.sqlite_connection
        sqlite_connection = self.open()
        try:
            cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
            if debug:
                print("Connected to SQLite")
            data_copy = cursor.execute("select count(*) from Password_Store")
            values = data_copy.fetchone()
            id = int(values[0]) + 1
            sqlite_insert_with_param = """INSERT INTO 'Password_Store'
                              ('id', 'desc', 'pass_hash') 
                              VALUES (?, ?, ?);"""

            data_tuple = (id, pw_description, new_passwd)
            cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_with_param, data_tuple)
            sqlite_connection.commit()
            if debug:
                print("Python Variables inserted successfully into SqliteDb_developers table")

        except sqlite3.Error as error:
            print("Failed to insert Python variable into sqlite table:", error)
            return False
        else:
            print('Stored password ok.')
        finally:
            self.close()

    def open_database(self):
        """
        Open the database
        :return: list(entries in database)
        """
        #  sqlite_connection = self.sqlite_connection
        sqlite_connection = self.open()
        try:
            cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
            if debug:
                print("Connected to SQLite")

            sqlite_select_query = """SELECT * from Password_Store"""
            cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
            records = cursor.fetchall()
            if debug:
                print("Total rows are:  ", len(records))
            id_desc = []
            for row in records:
                _id = int(row[0])
                _desc = str(row[1])
                id_desc.append([_id, _desc])
            return id_desc
        except sqlite3.Error as error:
            print("Failed to read data from sqlite table", error)
            return False
        except Exception as err:
            print('Unknown error:', err)
        finally:
            self.close()

    def select_from_db(self, id):
        """
        Grab a certain password from the database
        :param id: primary key of password to get
        :return: aes encrypted password
        """
        # sqlite_connection = self.sqlite_connection
        sqlite_connection = self.open()
        try:
            cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
            if debug:
                print("Connected to SQLite")

            sql_select_query = """select * from Password_Store where id = ?"""
            cursor.execute(sql_select_query, (id,))
            record = cursor.fetchone()
            if debug:
                print("Sql library: Retrieving ID:", id)
            return record

        except sqlite3.Error as error:
            print("Failed to read data from sqlite table", error)
            return False
        finally:
            self.close()

    def delete_from_database(self, id):
        sqlite_connection = self.open()
        try:
            cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
            if debug:
                print("Connected to SQLite")
            # Deleting single record now
            sql_delete_query = """DELETE from Password_Store where id = ?"""
            cursor.execute(sql_delete_query, (id,))
            sqlite_connection.commit()
            return "Record deleted successfully "

        except sqlite3.Error as error:
            print("Failed to delete record from sqlite table", error)
            return False
        finally:
            self.close()
```

Config Lib

```
debug = False
from os import getenv
config_dir = getenv('HOME') + '/.clipw'
config_file = config_dir + '/clipw.conf'
database_file = config_dir + '/clipw.db'
```

Main Logic:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
CliPassWord Manager - A Very Simple Python3 Powered Command Line Password Manager
Author: Darkerego ~ November, 2019 <xelectron@protonmail.com>
"""
import argparse
import shutil
import signal
import threading
from os import mkdir, kill, getpid
from os.path import isfile
from sys import argv

from lib import aes_lib
from lib import passlib
from lib import sql_functions
from lib.clipw_conf import *


def get_input(_type: str or int, _prompt: str):
    """
    Functions to get and validate input.
    :param _type: input type: str or int
    :param _prompt: input prompt
    :return: input
    """
    if _type == 'int':
        while True:
            try:
                io = int(input(_prompt))
            except TypeError:
                print('Enter a valid integer.')
            else:
                return io
    elif _type == 'str':
        while True:
            try:
                io = str(input(_prompt))
            except TypeError:
                print('Enter a valid string.')
            else:
                return io


def get_selection(_prompt: str, opts: list, _type: int or str):
    """
    Function to handle selecting input from a list of options
    :param _type:
    :param _prompt: input prompt
    :param opts: list of choices
    :return: selected option
    """
    while True:
        try:
            selection = _type(input(_prompt))
        except TypeError:
            print('Invalid input type.')
        else:
            if selection in opts:
                return selection
            else:
                print("%d is not a valid option" % selection)


def init_database():
    """
    Initialize the database
    :return:
    """
    print('Initializing database ... %s' % database_file)
    try:
        mkdir(config_dir)
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    if isfile(database_file):
        remove_db = input('[!] Database file found, would you like to delete it? (y/n) :')
        if remove_db.lower() == 'y':
            print('Making a backup of current database ...')
        shutil.move(database_file, database_file + '.orig')

    sql_ = sql_functions.Sql()
    hash_pass_ = passlib.HashPass()
    hash_pass_.store_master_password()

    if sql_.init_database():
        print('Successfully initialized the database.')
    sql_.close()
    aes.remove_from_mem()


def store_pass():
    """
    Store a password from standard input
    :return:
    """
    pw_description = input('Password Description: ')
    new_pass = hash_pass.store_password()
    encrypted_pw = aes.encrypt_data(new_pass)
    sql.append_database(encrypted_pw, pw_description)
    return True


def generate_random_pw(pw_len=None):
    pw_description = input('Password Description: ')
    if not pw_len:
        pw_len = [8]
    new_pw = hash_pass.random_password(pw_len[0])
    encrypted_pw = aes.encrypt_data(new_pw)
    sql.append_database(encrypted_pw, pw_description)
    #  print(str('Password: %s' % new_pw))
    return new_pw


def open_db():
    """
    Function to open the database and retrieve an entry
    :return:
    """
    id_desc = sql.open_database()
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('                      Password Database:                      ')
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------')
    for i in id_desc:
        print('ID: ', i[0], "Description", i[1])
    print('--------------------------------------------------------------')
    get_entry = get_input('int', 'Enter ID of password to decrypt: ')

    ret = sql.select_from_db(id=get_entry)
    if ret is None:
        print('%d is not a valid entry. Try again.' % get_entry)
    else:
        print("Id: ", ret[0])
        print("Description:", ret[1])
        hashed = ret[2]
        try:
            decrypted = aes.decrypt_data(hashed)
        except UnicodeDecodeError as err:
            print('Error decrypting password:', err)
        except Exception as err:
            print('Error decrypting password:', err)
        else:
            print('Password:', decrypted)


def edit_db_entry():
    """
    Function to edit a database entry
    :return:
    """
    id_desc = sql.open_database()
    ids = []
    for i in id_desc:
        print('ID: ', i[0], "Description", i[1])
        ids.append(i[0])
    entry_edit = get_selection(_prompt='Enter ID of entry to edit: ', opts=ids, _type=int)
    ret = sql.select_from_db(id=entry_edit)
    print('Fields: ')
    print('ID:', ret[0])
    print('[1] Description', ret[1])
    show_pass = input('Show password (y/n)? : ')
    if show_pass == 'y':
        hashed = ret[2]
        decrypted = aes.decrypt_data(hashed)
        print('[2] Password:', decrypted)
    else:
        print('[2] Password: x-x-x-x-x')

    edit_field = get_selection('Enter field of entry to edit. (1: Description, 2: Password)',
                               opts=[1, 2], _type=int)
    if edit_field == 1:
        new_description = input('Description: ')
        try:
            sql.edit_database(id=entry_edit, field='desc', data=new_description)
        except Exception as err:
            print('Error editing entry:', err)
        else:
            return True
    if edit_field == 2:
        suggest_password = input('Generate new random password? (y/n): ')
        if suggest_password == 'y':
            new_pw = hash_pass.random_password(16)
        else:
            new_pw = input('Enter new password: ')
        if new_pw is not None:
            encrypted_pw = aes.encrypt_data(new_pw)
            try:
                sql.edit_database(id=entry_edit, field='pass_hash', data=encrypted_pw)
            except Exception as err:
                print('Error editing entry:', err)
            else:
                return True
        else:
            print('Error: password is None.')
            return False


def delete_entry_from_db():
    """
    Function to delete an entry from the database.
    :return:
    """
    id_desc = sql.open_database()
    ids = []
    for i in id_desc:
        print('ID: ', i[0], "Description", i[1])
        ids.append(i[0])
    get = get_selection(_prompt='Entry to delete: ', opts=ids, _type=int)
    if debug:
        print('Retrieving: ', get)
    ret = sql.delete_from_database(id=get)
    if ret:
        print(ret)
    else:
        print('Error deleting from database.')
        return False


def get_args():
    """
    Argument parser
    :return: argparse generated object
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Python Cli Password Manager')
    parser.add_argument('--init', '--init_database', dest='init_db', action='store_true', help='Re|Init Database')
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--interactive', dest='interactive', action='store_true', default=False,
                        help='Interactive mode')
    parser.add_argument('-t,', '--timeout', default=600, type=int, dest='timeout', help='Override timeout - close after'
                                                                                        'this amount of seconds.')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--open', dest='open', help='Open the password database', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--store', dest='store', action='store_true', help='Enter and store a new password in'
                                                                                 ' the database')
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--edit', dest='edit', help='Edit an entry.', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--delete', dest='delete', help='Delete an entry', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--random', dest='gen_random', help='Generate and store a random password of n length',
                        type=int, default=None, nargs="*")

    return parser.parse_args()


def cleanup():
    """
    Cleanup function for security
    :return:
    """
    aes.remove_from_mem()


class TimeOutTime:
    """
    Empty object to hold specified timeout seconds
    """

    def __init__(self, secs):
        """
        Init Function
        :param secs: seconds before timeout
        """
        self.secs = secs

    def get(self):
        """
        Return specified seconds
        :return: secs
        """
        return int(self.secs)


def app():
    """
    Program main logic
    :return: -- print to stdout
    """
    args = get_args()
    try:
        program_name = argv[0]
    except Exception:
        program_name = 'clipw'

    global sql, hash_pass, aes

    if args.init_db:
        init_database()
        exit(0)
    else:
        if not (args.open or args.store or args.edit or args.delete or args.gen_random or args.interactive):
            print("Run %s -i for interactive or --help for usage" % program_name)
            exit(1)
        sql = sql_functions.Sql()
        hash_pass = passlib.HashPass()
        aes = aes_lib.HandleAes(key=hash_pass.get_master_password())

        if args.interactive:
            timeout = args.timeout
            to = TimeOutTime(timeout)
            wd = Watchdog(to.get())
            wd.start()
            print('Running in interactive mode. ')
            while True:
                try:
                    action = get_selection("Enter action: store (s), generate: (g), open and select entry: (o), "
                                           "edit entry: "
                                           "(e), delete entry: (d), quit program (q) ",
                                           opts=["s", "g", "o", "e", "d", "q"], _type=str)
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    break
                except Exception as err:
                    print(err)
                else:
                    try:
                        sql = sql_functions.Sql()
                    except Exception as err:
                        if debug:
                            print('Error with SQL:', err)
                        pass
                    wd.refresh()
                    action = action.lower()
                    print('Selected:', action)
                    if action == 's':
                        store_pass()
                    elif action == 'g':
                        pw_len = get_input('int', 'Password Length: ')
                        ret = generate_random_pw([pw_len])
                        if ret:
                            print('Password:', ret)
                    elif action == 'o':
                        open_db()
                    elif action == 'e':
                        edit_db_entry()
                    elif action == 'd':
                        delete_entry_from_db()
                    elif action == 'q':
                        break
                    else:
                        raise ValueError('Invalid Selection')
            print('Quitting...')
            wd.do_expire()

        if args.store:
            store_pass()

        if args.gen_random is not None:
            pw_len = args.gen_random
            ret = generate_random_pw(pw_len)
            if ret:
                print("Password", ret)

        if args.open:
            open_db()

        if args.edit:
            edit_db_entry()

        if args.delete:
            delete_entry_from_db()
        # Remove the master key from memory on exit
        cleanup()


class Watchdog:
    def __init__(self, _timeout=600):
        self.timeout = _timeout
        self._t = None
        self.wd_debug = False  # debug messages

    def do_expire(self):
        cleanup()
        kill(getpid(), signal.SIGKILL)

    def _expire(self):
        print("\nTimeout expired, exiting for security...")
        self.do_expire()

    def start(self):
        if self._t is None:
            self._t = threading.Timer(self.timeout, self._expire)
            self._t.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self._t is not None:
            self._t.cancel()
            self._t = None

    def refresh(self):
        if self.wd_debug:
            print('Debug message: watchdog refresh.')
        if self._t is not None:
            self.stop()
            self.start()


def main():
    try:
        app()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Caught Signal, exiting ...')
    finally:
        exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Other Notes & Questions:

- Is there a "cleaner" way to kill the process if it's been idle for (in this case) ten minutes? It seems kind of of "hacky" to use `os.kill()`, but I can't seem to find a way to simply use `exit(0)` while importing functions from multiple libaries.
- I know this program is kind of rudimentary right now. I intend on adding additional fields to the database such as (timestamp) "created" and "last modified", as well as more details like "username" and "url", instead of just having an id and description for each corresponding password.
- I am trying to think of a good method for securely sharing a database between different devices. Personally I just use ssh in these cases, however a friend of mine said he would like an easier way to do it. I considered perhaps encrypting the database again with an "export password" and then uploading to a service like spruge.us or termbin.com, so that the user could retrieve and import the database easily on another device. (Thoughts on this?)
- I am mostly looking for critique on how the program handles password hashing and the encryption functionality, however am open to any other suggestions and critique. Thank you for taking the time to review this code!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to review each lib separately, so there might be duplicates.

## Hash Library

### Returns

In your `generate_hash` method, you have this section of code:

```
...
    return salt, pw_hash
else:
    return False
```

The else is unnecessary here, as the first return will exit the method. It should look like this instead:

```
...
    return salt, pw_hash
return False
```

### Types

In some methods, you use types to display what parameters are accepted and what values are returned, but in other methods you do not. I would recommend being consistent to one idea: using types or not using them. My personal preference is using types to have as much description about the methods I write.

When returning two different types of values in a method, use `Union`. It allows you to do something like this:

```
def get_master_password(self) -> Union[str, None]:
```

This says it will either return a string, or None. You can describe this possible behavior in the method docstring.

### Asserts

Instead of using try and catches, you can assert *with* an error message as such:

```
assert pw == pw2, 'Passwords do not match. Try again'
```

### Naming

Personally, I see `pw` and `pw2` as less than desirable variable names. Names like `password` and then `confirm_password` can be more descriptive. The same when working with files, you use `ff` when `with open(...) as file` is more clear.

### Inheritance

Subclassing from `object` isn't required, as it's a python 2 feature. You don't need to inherit from object to have new style in python 3. All classes are new-style. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) is a StackOverflow post that explains what new-style is.

### Init Method

If you don't need an `init` method, don't bother writing one. It's unnecessary code.

---

## AES Library

Nothing much to review, just going to reiterate not having to inherit from object when creating a new class and the possible use of types. For example:

```
def encrypt_data(self, data):
```

can be

```
def encrypt_data(self, data: str) -> str:
```

(I'm assuming the data passed is a string)

---

## SQL Library

### Reserved Names

I wouldn't use `id` within this program, as it's a reserved name in python. A fix most python developers use (from what I've seen) is `_id` or `id_`. You use `_id` in some parts of your program, so I would recommend using it everywhere.

The same goes with `open`. I would suggest a method like `connect_to_database`.

### Types

Again, types.

### Docstring Formatting

Just some food for thought about your docstrings. This is your `edit_database` docstring:

```
"""
Broken function to update a field of a row in the table
:param id: primary key id for WHERE clause
:param data: edited field data to replace in current db entry
:param field: either desc (description) or pass_hash (password hash of entry)
:return: True om success, false om fail
"""
```

It's a little clunky and slightly hard to read since it's one block of code. Personally, I would separate the method description, parameters accepted, and values returned:

```
"""
Broken function to update a field of a row in the table

:param id: primary key id for WHERE clause
:param data: edited field data to replace in current db entry
:param field: either desc (description) or pass_hash (password hash of entry)

:return: True om success, false om fail
"""
```

Now everything looks neater and you can differentiate the parts of the docstring.

---

## Main Logic

### String Formatting

This

```
print('Initializing database ... %s' % database_file)
```

can be

```
print(f'Initializing database ... {database_file}')
```

Using `f""` strings allows you to directly place variables in your strings without having to use `%s` or `.format(...)`.

### `or` in parameters

This

```
def get_input(_type: str or int, _prompt: str):
```

can be

```
def get_input(_type: Union[str, int], _prompt: str) -> Union[str, int]:
```

It utilizes `typing`s `Union` instead of using a built in keyword such as `or`.

Comment: Awesome review, thanks so much! Definitely a lot of great tips in there, I will refactor my code using your suggestions. I always wondered how to use `Union`, I did not know you could use `assert` in that manner (much cleaner) . Do you have any insight on whether or not my encryption functionality is implemented properly and is reasonably secure? Thanks again!